# WPF MVVM customer -> address

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

In a WPF application following MVVM pattern I have a Customer class which has a property of type Address.

In my CustomerViewModel I create a new datacontext and get my customer with this, I also have my bog standard properties, forename, surname, etc... but how would I hook my address object into the customer view model? Do I:

1. Simply replicate all the address properties in my customerVM
2. Create an AddressViewModel and hold a reference to this as my
   Address property? If this is the way how would I get the datacontext
   into the AddressViewModel instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose plan B.

create AddressVM, add it as a dependency property to CustomerVM, and use it like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Address.AddressString}"/>
```

you don't need to set DataContext for subclasses. you have access to them via '.'

Comment: Cheers Bizz but if my AddressVM has a datacontext also then when I come to save from the CustomerVM won't I also have to save from the addressVM?

Comment: (if I understood your issue correctly) It depends on your DataService design. If you have a separate DataService for Address, then it would be easier to save from AddressVM rather than extracting address from customer and then save it from CustomerVM. on the other hand, if you have only CustomerDS (no AddressDS), then not only I'd choose plan A, but also I'd remove any Address class from project. you know. keep it consistent.